# How to limit query time in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

If you use [query_string](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/query-string-query/) in [elasticsearch](http://www.elasticsearch.org/) with an unlucky query over a large dataset, you can almost bring the cluster down, and it can take quite a long time until the query is finished. This can be a serious problem if you allow the users to specify arbitrary query strings.

So, is there a way to limit the time and/or resources the query takes? If you could tell elasticsearch to abort the querying automatically after, say, 10 seconds, that'd help quite a lot.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can pass a search "timeout" in the [request body](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/search/request-body/) or in the [uri request](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/search/uri-request/). If the search request times out before collecting all results, the partial results will be returned.

Here's a uri request example for 10 seconds (units are in milliseconds):

```
http://localhost:9200/_search?timeout=10000
```

If you set the timeout low enough, the returned json will show "timed_out":true.

Comment: Note that although this does cause elastic to return a response after the timeout has elapsed (ish), it [doesn't prevent](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/issues/3627) the server from finishing the query execution and is therefore no use in limiting server load. See also [#4586](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/pull/4586) and [#2929](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/issues/2929)

Comment: The only relevant recent updates seem to be https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/9156#issuecomment-99557275

Comment: ie any parameter which can kill the query if its taking a longer time

Answer (score 1):

The search timeout can be configurable at query time and also it can be configurable via cluster settings to apply all your searches.

```
GET test_index/_search
{
  "timeout": "60s", 
  "query": {},
  "aggs": {}
}
```

You can update cluster settings to set timeout to all queries.

```
PUT /_cluster/settings
{
  "persistent": {
    "search.default_search_timeout": "60s"
  }
}
```

**Note**: The query timeout is not guaranteed. In some cases (especially in very large indices) the timeout operation may fail.
To set a cluster-wide default timeout for all search requests, configure search.default_search_timeout using the cluster settings API. This global timeout duration is used if no timeout argument is passed in the request. If the global search timeout expires before the search request finishes, the request is cancelled using task cancellation. The search.default_search_timeout setting defaults to -1 (no timeout).

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-your-data.html